# How to implement trip advisor api to get rating and review about a specific hotel

Tags: java, api, rest

I am implementing this REST URL to get data

```
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/map/28.5441005,77.2132106?key=<user-key>          <key>
```

I am getting list of hotels but i want "rating" and "reviews" for a specific hotel.
How can I get that?

How can I get rating and reviews for a specific hotel?

Where are we defining hotel co-ordinate?. name ?

In case of review I didn't find URL for specific hotel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch hotel id then you need to hit this url first

```
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/map/lat,lng?key=http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/map/lat,lng?key=<YOUR TRIP ADVISOR KEY>
```

In response, you will get JSON in which your required hotel will be there. And, there you can find

```
"location_id":"xxxxxx"
```

On getting that location ID, you can hit below url to get ratings, reviews & other required data:

```
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/place above location_id here/hotels?key=<YOUR TRIP ADVISOR KEY>
```

This is the only way so far to get above things done.

Comment: yes it work .. now tried to integrate it in my java code by              RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Address_Obj obj = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URI, Address_Obj.class);                                        but getting RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.sucl.tripAdvisor.Address_Obj]

Comment: If it works then you should accept & up vote it first

Comment: i accept the answer but can't vote as i have only 6 reputation point . Iwill do it for sure once i would reach to 10.